# Blender 2.8: Very hard to see selected vertices & edges in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges

I am running Blender 2.8 2019-04-30 hash e8daa615704b and it is very hard to see selected vertices & edges in edit mode. In the attached image the left and top edges on the forward face are selected, and if I look very closely I cna see that, but it is not nearly as easy to see as it was in 2.79 or in videos I have seen of 2.80. I also had the same result with an earlier version (f32902e6dacf) from on or about 2019-04-23.

Is there a preference I can set to make this more visible? I understand this is beta software and I may just have to wait. If it isn't controllable via a preference value then I will look to see if a bug has been filed.

Thanks, Matthew

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the edge edit mode in your screenshot is displayed with default line width, you may want to check the **overlay's option** in the 3D View panel header bar.

After entering the edit mode, **Mesh Edit Mode** options will appear in there. Without the **center checkbox** been checked, the line display in edge mode will be slightly bigger then normal to make difference from face mode.

[image: Center dot in edit-mode change the display behavior in edge mode]

And for vertex mode,
you can change directly in `Setting >> Themes >> 3D View >> Certex Size`, but the line width won't change either.

An alternative way is changing `Setting >> Interface >> Line Width` to **thic**, making literally everything bigger than usual. Which might not be the best solution.

[image: Line Width setting in Blender 2.8]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I will dig into the Themes area; that looks really powerful.

Comment: Also setting the Line Width to Thick was perfect for my 4K monitor.