# Is there a way to increase visibility of the "Edge lines" in blender 2.8

Tags: interface, edges, topology

I'm currently following a tutorial using blender 2.8. As you can see in the pictures the "edge lines" are much more visible in pre 2.8 which makes it a lot easier to see the direction of the edge loops. Is there any way to change this so it becomes more like the old interface?

Cheers!
[image]

Comment: May try this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139457/blender-2-8-very-hard-to-see-selected-vertices-edges-in-edit-mode , I am also finding a better solution now.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried tweaking the things mentioned in the post and it made it slightly better. After a closer inspection however I think the difference might be that the edge lines in the picture on the right is actually following the topology of the mesh while in my version they are "hovering around it" sorta like a cage surrounding it. This makes the lines clip through the model at certain points.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to display different behavior in the sub-mod.

[image: submod option]

The *old one* you mention let both these option turn on, making the sub-modifer directly show in edit mode.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Please consider to make it as an accepted answer, while it is't the perfect one though.